# MigraDoc Table not continuing to next page

Tags: c#, migradoc

I dont know if this is something I have done as I feel what i am getting is not the 'out of the box' functionality of a table in Migradoc. Basically I have a large table where the columns span beyond the height of the page. As you can see from the screenshot it seems to just continue off the first page over the footer leaving the next page blank with just the table header.

[image]

I would like the table to identify the end of the page and then continue on the next page under the Table header row.

The table is setup with the following properties:

```
table.KeepTogether = false;
table.Borders.Width = 0.5f;
```

and the first/header row is marked as such with just:

```
row.HeadingFormat = true;
```

The only other thing that may be note-worthy but have not yet looked into is that each cell contains a sub table containing the Checkbox, Label Text and small description beneath.

Is/Are there properties i may be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables break to the next page, but table rows do not break.

If you have a single row that is larger than the page then it will not break and will be written over the page boundary.

The only properties that matter are `HeadingFormat` and `KeepWithNext`.

Comment: Now that makes sense... I will take a look to see if this is what is happening... I am almost certain that is the case?!

Comment: The Table is being generated with just one BIG row so looks like I have a little reverse engineering to do to get this rendered correctly. Thanks for putting me on the right path!

Comment: Following the above revelation I was able to address my then-issue by applying rows appropriately. I have now however come across some rather large RTF user-inputs that are rendered to a single cell. There is no obvious way of splitting them across many rows and as a result end up falling off the bottom of the page. A new page is created, MigraDoc just doesnt know to start using it. Is there some method I might be able to override/inherit that will give me more control over page-breaks?

Comment: Large multi-page user input is not really suitable for tables. When you add these long texts as one or more paragraphs outside a table, then automatic page breaks will occur and everything will look fine. Maybe set a threshold and show texts with more than e.g. 1000 characters outside a table.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I have started going down the path of paragraphs for these particular fields now so hopefully that will see me fit. It does mean I have less flexibility with my paragraphs I think though (i.e. one next to the other) but I guess I should be able to apply borders to the paragraph and make it look like a single column table?